# Is premier league tv rights money divided among all 20 teams equally?

Tags: football, finances, media, english-premier-league

Premier League just signed a massive 3 year GBP 5.136 billion deal. Does the amount divided among the 20 premier league clubs equally ? or the teams who finish higher in the table get more money than the teams finishing lower in the able ?

Just seen this article ( http://www.totalsportek.com/money/premier-league-tv-rights-money-distribution/ ) which says that money from oversees tv deals is divided equally and money from domestic tv rights deal is divided 50% equally, 25% according to how teams finish in the table and 25% with each time a match is shown live on tv in uk.

any idea if its true ? because in La Liga top team (real Madrid & Barcelon) get the bigger chunk of the tv rights money. answers will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: The site swissramble.blogspot.com has lots of detail on the finance of the Premier League.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Article you have read seems pretty spot on. So a part is equally divided, another part is divided based on their final standing in the league. Can't really expand further then the article you provided.

You can't really compare the Premier League with the Primera Division on that. The English stick together and sell their individual TV rights together and divide them - more or less - equally among themselves. In Spain the big clubs rather fly solo and sell their rights individually to the highest bidders because they do not want to share their piece of the pie with the little teams.

Comment: Goes to show the quality in England vs. Spain. It's common knowledge that only making it to the Premier league, clubs earn large sums of money.